# Bind external command output to a socket?

Tags: ruby, sockets, unix-socket

I'm looking for a working example how connect standard output of spawned external command to a unix socket.
So far, I put up following snippet.

```
require 'socket'

class XkbSocket
  def initialize
    @sock_cld, @sock_par = UNIXSocket.pair
    at_exit {@sock_cld.close; @sock_par.close}
    pid = spawn 'xkb-switch -W', @sock_cld => @sock_par
    Process.detach pid
  rescue Errno::ENOENT
    @sock_cld.puts "N/A"
  end
end
```

I am using socket pair, however they are not mapped to some real files so inaccessible for other clients.

I'd like to update above example, so it will create `/tmp/mysocket` file for external consumers.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that's the path? It's not specified in your code.

Comment: I'm sure it is not specified in the snippet. That's why am I asking to add it. Sockets created by `UNIXSocket.pair` have empty path, ie not associated with any file, but I need it for other programs to connect in.

Comment: That's why you call [`new`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/UNIXSocket.html) with a path name, not `pair` which does exactly what you say. One program calls `listen`, the other calls `open`.

Comment: @tadman How can spawned non-ruby process call `open` ? That was the point. `STDOUT` of non-ruby process redirected to a unix socket and a ruby process as a socket client (consumer).

Comment: You could use tools like [`open3`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) to forward output from one process to a socket you've opened. Don't forget that UNIX sockets that are opened with `new` act a lot like files so you can  just redirect output to them using the shell.